# Touching the timestamp of models without actually updating the model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

There have been a lot of questions asking how one can prevent the `updated_at` column from changing when nothing was changed. In fact, [this was even fixed as a bug.](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/790)

However, I would like to do just the opposite. I wish to update the `updated_at` column to the current timestamp, despite nothing being changed. Essentially, I would like to [`touch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_(Unix)) my model if you will.

`$ touch MyLaravelModel`

**Is there a easy way to do something like this in Laravel?** Something equivalent to `$model->touch()` as opposed to manually editing the field?

I have already tried something like this, but absolutely nothing happens.

```
$model = Model::find(1);
$model->save();
```

The reason I'm doing this is because I would like to use the `updated_at` column to essentially keep track of when the model was last "viewed", without necessarily changing it. Is there a better way to go about this?

This is different from [Touching Parent Timestamp](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#touching-parent-timestamps) because in this case, my model does not belong to a parent nor does it have any children.

Comment: Where's the attempted code?

Comment: @aldrin27 I'm not exactly sure what to attempt. The best I've came up with was just doing `$model->save()`. However, according to my [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/790) it was a bug and got fixed.

Comment: I think you can use the query builders to touch only the `updated_at` and `created_at` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `touch()` method. It's in the [`Model`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1344) abstract class and has been since at least v4.0.

Here it is:

```
/**
 * Update the model's update timestamp.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function touch()
{
    $this->updateTimestamps();
    return $this->save();
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$model->touch();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do myObject->save() and that will update the updated_at field of the current object even if nothing was changed. So lets say it was a user:

```
$myUser = User::find(1);
$myUser->save()
```

I believe that would still update the updated_at time.

Comment: It does not seem to work for me. According to [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/790), it was considered a bug and was fixed.

Comment: ahhh I see. I apologize for the incorrect answer then. The only solution I see in mind at the moment is what you said you'd prefer not to do which is manually update the timestamp :-/